# Why the program returns acces violation?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why does this program returns access violation every time I run it?

```
void sort_lines(char *tp[], int n)
{
    int sortat = 0, i;
    char *temp;
    while (!sortat)
    {
        sortat = 1;
        for (i = 0; i<n-1; i++)
            if (strcmp(tp[i], tp[i+1])<0)
            {
                temp = tp[i];
                tp[i] = tp[i+1];
                tp[i+1] = temp;
                sortat = 0;
            }
    }  
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char *sir[7] = { "mama", "mananca", "mancare", "facuta", "doar", "de", "ea" };
    int m = 7;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", sir[i]);
    }
    sort_lines(sir, m);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", sir[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Seems that if i restart my pc it works 10 times out of 11. It is driving me nuts. I dont really understand why.

Comment: The array is in read only memory

Comment: No, the strings may be in read only memory, but the contents of array "sir" are pointers to these strings, and they are definetly in read/write RAM (it's a variable after all)

Comment: FYI, I recommend always including braces in the body of `for` loops that are multiple lines -- even if it's only the `if` statement (and its body).

Comment: When you run it under a debugger, and single-step it, what line segfaults?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have have forgotten to include `stdio.h` and `string.h` in your program. With that two includes, your program works for me (ah! well, and the `;` after `return 0` at the last line).

Comment: Indeed, it works well for me.  I even ran it through `valgrind`, which gave it a clean bill of health.

Comment: they are included, i just skipped over them. I am using Microsoft visual studio 2013 and mt source file is Source.c but into a win 32 aplication project for c++...

Comment: Something might be screwing with `printf()` or `strcmp()`. Try this: change the string format of your `printf`'s from `"%s"` to `"%X"`. This is to print the contents of each element of `sir` as the hexadecimal representation of the address it contains (i.e., just a number). Then, change the line with `strcmp(tp[i],tp[i+1])<0` to `tp[i]<tp[i+1]` to compare the addresses themselves. This won't sort your strings, but will help you to run your code with minimal changes to see if it still segfaults or not. The last loop should print a list of hex addresses in descendent order.